# Transferring between IaaS providers with only raw images of instances and volumes

Tags: image, cloud, instance, volume, iaas

My system runs on a cloud environment provided by an academic research computing organization. Problem is, it's unreliable, service is bad, and it can be slow.

So I'm considering switching to a different cloud provider, but I want to know whether it is possible to create a new compute instance and volume from just snapshots (raw images) of those instances and volumes? I asked DigitalOcean and they said this isn't possible (I'd have to create a new droplet and reinstall/transfer everything).

I've also emailed AWS but no response yet. If this is possible (just because it seems like the simplest route), are there any recommendations of cloud providers?

My system is running Ubuntu with Apache and MySQL. It hosts a wordpress website, a large database, and a series of Java tools. The instance snapshot is about 20gb and the storage volume is 250gb.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What image format will you get from your institution? There is cli tool “qemu-img convert” between format and it seems possible to make an ami instance (https://www.elastic.co/blog/create-an-ami-from-your-own-vm-image)

Comment: It's just a raw image file (no extension). So from an AMI I can create an instance on AWS? And attach my volume instance to it?